# CakePHP not checking form validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, view, model

I'm writing a contact form and want to add some simple validation routines. The action for this page looks like this:

```
public function contact() {
    $this->loadModel('Contact');

    $this->set('pageTitle', 'Contact me');
}
```

and the `Contact` model is this:

```
<?php

class Contact extends AppModel {
public $useTable = false;

public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 60),
            'message' => 'Between 1 and 60 characters in length'
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'kosher' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'Please make sure your email is entered correctly'
        ),
    ),
    'message' => array(
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 65000),
            'message' => 'Between 1 and 65000 characters in length'
        )
    )
);
```

}

and finally my view page:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Contact'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('message', array('type' => 'textarea')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Send', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
```

However, when I submit the form with incorrect values the validation routines aren't called and no error messages are shown.

How can I get Cake to validate the form?

Answer (score 0):

In your contact action all you are doing is loading the Contact model. You have to explicitly call the relevant model method to perform validation. Read the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html) properly for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the documentation for how to insert/update data from a form in the controller. You'll see something like this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
        // handle the success.
    } else {
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Contact could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```